# "noirq suspend" in the linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, power-management, suspend

What does `noirq suspend` mean in the context of the linux kernel ?I've come across this log in the output of `dmesg` :

```
PM: noirq suspend of devices failed
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: One of the `->suspend_noirq()` PM callback failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment made by @0andriy, I found the description of that in the linux kernel source code([`include/linux/pm.h`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/pm.h)) :

> @suspend_noirq: Complete the actions started by @suspend().  Carry out any
> additional operations required for suspending the device that might be
> racing with its driver's interrupt handler, which is guaranteed not to
> run while @suspend_noirq() is being executed.
> It generally is expected that the device will be in a low-power state
> (appropriate for the target system sleep state) after subsystem-level
> @suspend_noirq() has returned successfully.  If the device can generate
> system wakeup signals and is enabled to wake up the system, it should be
> configured to do so at that time.  However, depending on the platform
> and device's subsystem, @suspend() or @suspend_late() may be allowed to
> put the device into the low-power state and configure it to generate
> wakeup signals, in which case it generally is not necessary to define
> @suspend_noirq().